# How to define custom location for crossdomain.xml file?

Tags: search, ssl, ftp, root, crossdomain.xml

I'm using FTP over SSL and hence root directory cannot be accessed by me.

www.xyz.com/crossdomain.xml (default search location) does not exist. I want the target search location to be www.xyz.com/klm/crossdomain.xml

I have no clue how to proceed further. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to locate it at non-root directory, you need to add "site-control: permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"".
like below

crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

AS

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.example.com/klm/crossdomain.xml");
```